# RDLC reporting windowsforms en net8 visual studio 2022 ultima version

Tags: c#, rdlc

El rdlc no funciona correctamente, no me deja añadir el dataset y el control no se ve en el toolbox.
¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Has instalado el plugin? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio2022

Comment: Si y todo igual que en el framework 4.8 y en Net no funciona.